# Mapping relational MongoDB data in website : help needed

Tags: database, mongodb, sqlite, parse-platform

I run an Android app which locates OBJECTS with attributes like *ID, Name, Owner, Type, Place_ID* which are linked to PLACES, on a map. PLACES have attributes like *ID, Latitude, Longitude, Opening Hour, Closing Hour,...* The data is stored in a MongoDB on Back4App and I want to keep that way. I have one class for OBJECTS and one class for PLACES. The relation between OBJECTS and PLACES is not "a MongoDB relation", it is just a common String field in the OBJECTS and PLACES classes. 
In order to allow offline access to the data and to minimize DB server requests, the app synchronizes a local SQLITE database on the device with the MongoDB online database. In the Android App, the queries are passed to the SQLITE DB.

I'm trying to make a website which does the same job as the app, which is displaying filtered data from the MongoDB.

I started with a simple html and javascript website using the Parse SDK, but I'm facing a few difficulties.

A simple query is to list all the OBJECTS in a 50km radius, i.e. I need the OBJECTS **and** the PLACE where they are located. However, where I could get this easilty with a SELECT...JOIN in SQLITE, I cannot get this information through a simple Parse query because I want to know the OBJECTS too. And I cannot run 2 asynchronous queries in a for loop.

What website architecture and/or languages would you recommend for this type of website ?

How would you recommend to proceed ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: ZeekHuge opened my eyes on the bad design of not using pointers. After implementing pointers in my MongoDB, here's the lines of codes which did it for me :

```
Parse.initialize("", "");
Parse.serverURL = '';

var eiffel = new Parse.GeoPoint(48.858093, 2.294694);
var myScores = '';
var Enseigne = Parse.Object.extend("ENSEIGNE");
var Flipper = Parse.Object.extend("FLIPPER");

var query = new Parse.Query(Flipper);
var innerquery = new Parse.Query(Enseigne);
innerquery.withinKilometers("ENS_GEO",eiffel,500);

query.equalTo("FLIP_ACTIF", true);
query.include("FLIP_ENSPOINT");
query.include("FLIP_MODPOINT");
query.matchesQuery("FLIP_ENSPOINT", innerquery);
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var object = results[i];      
      myScores += '<tr><td>' + object.get('FLIP_MODPOINT').get('MOFL_NOM')
      + '</td><td>' + object.get('FLIP_ENSPOINT').get('ENS_NOM')
      + '</td><td>' + object.get('FLIP_ENSPOINT').get('ENS_GEO').latitude
      + '</td><td>' + object.get('FLIP_ENSPOINT').get('ENS_GEO').longitude
      + '</td></tr>';
    }
    (function($) {
      $('#results-table').append(myScores);
    })(jQuery);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: *The relation between OBJECTS and PLACES is not "a MongoDB relation", it is just a common String field in the OBJECTS and PLACES classes.* : That actually is a bad design, and there is no solution to bad design. Infact, a `Parse-pointer` could have saved all this.

Comment: I know it is pretty bad. If I fixed that and made proper pointers, how would it make it simpler for my needs for the website requests?

Comment: You can create a query that would automatically fetch the pointed object, in a single main query.

Comment: Okay, I understand after putting the Pointers relations in place, I can use query.include(*POINTER*) to get all the properties of the linked object, correct ?

Comment: yes, it is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by replacing the database keys by pointers and using the Innerquery and include functions. See exemple mentionned in question.